# Extracting elements from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string 'http://this.is.my.url:007/directory1/directory2/index.html' and I need to extract the string as below. Please advice the best way

var one = http://this.is.my.url:007/directory1/directory2/index

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var url = 'http://this.is.my.url:007/directory1/directory2/index.html';
url.replace(/\.[^.]*$/g, ''); // would replace all file extensions at the end.

// or in case you only want to remove .html, do this:
var url = 'http://this.is.my.url:007/directory1/directory2/index.html';
url.replace(/\.html$/g, '');
```

The $ character when included in a regular expression matches to the end of the text string. In variant a you look start at the  "." and remove everything from the this character until the end of the string. In variant 2, you reduce this to the exact string ".html". This is more about regular expressions than about javascript. To learn more about it, here is one of many nice [tutorials](http://andymatthews.net/read/2009/10/22/A-beginners-guide-to-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use `replace()`:

```
var url = 'http://this.is.my.url:007/directory1/directory2/index.html';
var one = url.replace('.html', '');
```

If want to ensure you only remove the `.html` from the end of the string use regex:

```
var url = 'http://this.is.my.url:007/directory1/directory2/index.html';
var one = url.replace(/\.html$/', '');
```

The `$` indicates that only the last characters of the string should be checked.

Comment: That won't work when the string ".html" appears in some other context in the input.

Comment: That's true, but why would it unless you have a TERRIBLE URL structure.

Comment: You mean unless *someone somewhere on the whole internet* has a terrible URL structure. Also, what about domains starting with html?

Answer (score 3):

```
var url = 'http://this.is.my.url:007/directory1/directory2/index.html';
var trimmedUrl = url.replace('.html', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `slice` the string up to the last dot:

```
var url = 'http://this.is.my.url:7/directory1/directory2/index.html';
url = url.slice(0,url.lastIndexOf('.')); 
  //=> "http://this.is.my.url:7/directory1/directory2/index"
```

Or in one line:

```
var url = ''.slice.call(
           url='http://this.is.my.url:7/directory1/directory2/index.html',
           0,url.lastIndexOf('.')  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression, it replaces everything (`.*`) with itself from the capture group (not including the trailing `.html`).

```
var url = 'http://this.is.my.url:007/directory1/directory2/index.html';
var one = url.replace(/(.*)\.html/, '$1');
                       ^  ^          ^^
// Capture group ______|  |__________||
//                    Capture ---->  Get captured content
```